# How to implement remove() method in binary search tree iterator

Tags: java, iterator, binary-tree

I'm implementing the binary search tree, here is the most important part of my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BinaryTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Iterable<BinaryTree.Entry> {
    private Entry<K, V> root;

    // inOrder iterator
    @Override
    public Iterator<BinaryTree.Entry> iterator() {
        return new InOrderIterator(root);
    }

    class InOrderIterator implements Iterator<BinaryTree.Entry> {
        Entry root;
        Stack<Entry> stack = new Stack<>();

        private void pushLeftChildren(Entry root) {
            while (root != null) {
                stack.push(root);
                root = root.left;
            }
        }

        public InOrderIterator(Entry root) {
            this.root = root;
            pushLeftChildren(root);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !stack.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public Entry next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("All nodes have been visited!");
            }

            Entry poped = stack.pop();
            pushLeftChildren(poped.right);

            return poped;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {

        }
    }

    class Entry<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
        K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K, V> left;
        Entry<K, V> right;


        Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K, V> left, Entry<K, V> right) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to implement remove() method in that inOrder traversing iterator, even usually it's marked as throwing unsupported operation exception.
Can you give me some advice how to do that if it is possible?

Comment: You just have to remove the current node under the iteration from the tree. So you just have to provide a remove operation in your tree and call it from the iterator. Of course this operation may depend on what you want to do with the siblings when removing a node. This may seem simple but modifying a structure while iterating over it is not trivial.

Comment: You know, I have spent a little time to think about it and you are right, modifying a structure while iterating isn't that trivial at all. The problem is that when remove() method goes and the node that has to be removed has both its children - rotation happens and some data is lost. The problem is that after searching over the internet for hours I didn't find any example at all, it's everywhere "throws Unsupported operation exception" and that's pretty it.

Comment: The other problem is that for example I have written 2 iterators with remove methods each(post- and inOrder) and they work right at some test examples, but I'm not sure if they work at every tests and I dont know how to test it propertly.

Comment: Another way to do it is to construct the whole list of ordered nodes at the construction of the iterator, let the user iterates over this list and delete nodes both in the list and in the tree when needed.

Comment: thank you, I was thinking about that